# Comparing numbers in various forms from a shell script

Tags: bash

I'm going to be retrieving two numbers as strings into variables A and B:

A will be in the form:

> "10" or "0x0A" or "0x0a"

In other words, A will be either a decimal or hexadecimal number (with 0x prefix).

B will be in the form:

> "image-000A" or "image-000a"

B will always be "image-" followed by 4 hexadecimal digits.

I need to compare the two numeric values and test if B > A. How do I do that in a shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a hex number to decimal simply by multiplying it by 1.

```
rojo@pico:~$ t=0x0a
rojo@pico:~$ echo $t
0x0a
rojo@pico:~$ echo $(( $t * 1 ))
10
```

Scraping the hex value from the image is slightly more complicated, but still works the same way.

```
rojo@pico:~$ t=image-000a
rojo@pico:~$ echo $t
image-000a
rojo@pico:~$ echo $(( 0x${t##image-} * 1 ))
10
```

The `${t##image-}` strips `image-` out of `$t`, leaving `000a`.